# Wordpress: Is there a way to load images in Media gallery directly from disk?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and I've deleted a bunch of images in Media page. Since I do a regular backup of disks I can manually recover them, but once they are present in disk they won't show up in Media page because they don't exist anymore in database. I can't restore the database because I would miss lots of recently changes.

So, what I want to do is Media page to load those images directly from disk (eg: wp-content/uploads/2017/01/blabla.png). Any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your database, you have your GUID(in wp_post table) data for Images? If you have then you can simply add your images by FTP. But make sure that you have GUID data, you have to create directory wise add your images in the upload folder.

Comment: Nop, that's the problem. I don't have anything in database. In other words, consider these images as new ones, so I need a way WP get them just by reading a certain directory.